# Change specificity by child

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I'd like to integrate a theme tag to my elements so they appear in diffrent colours. But since the css selectors have the same css specificity the latest overrides the earlier defined rule.

this is an example that shows my problem:

```
<div class="red">
  <div class="box">This should be red</div>
  <div class="yellow">
    ...
        <div class="box">This should be yellow (nested in x levels under the div.yellow)</div>
    ...
</div>
```

and here my css

```
.box { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.red { background-color: red; }
```

the box should be listed somewhere, but as soon as it is a sub child of another color definition it should been overwritten.

thanks for any help!

Comment: is this dynamically made?? if not just use : class="box yellow" as its class

Comment: It is yellow. I'm guessing the problem is elsewhere. Probably involving all the content of .yellow being floated or .box being absolutely positioned. Whatever the issue is, it isn't with the code you've shown us.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be doing things this way -- if your theme changes, then suddenly things with class `yellow` may actually be blue, for example. I would suggest finding a common way of naming things (even if it's just `colour1`, `colour2`, `colour-highlight`...) and then specifying those styles. You can then look into the way your pages are designed and make the rules more specific as necessary (either by using `!important` or by making the rule more specific, e.g. `.colour1` becoming `.box .colour1` or `div.colour1`).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree that doing things this way is not good practice. The code was just a simple example because my elements and code are more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.box { background-color: inherit;  }
```

See:
http://jsbin.com/imube/edit

Answer (score 0):

I don’t quite see the problem. Here’s what I get with that code:

[alt text http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/images/so/1905834.png](http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/images/so/1905834.png)

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to use CSS's **!important** keyword eg:

```
.yellow { background-color: yellow !important;}
```

Comment: That would overwrite the settings but is bad practice.

Comment: I don’t think it would solve the problem either. If you just put !important on the yellow class, then yellow will always take precedence, regardless of nesting. If you put it on all the colour classes, then you’re back where you started.